# How to make child div visible when browser window size changing?

Tags: html, css

If I have two nested `div` element on my ***index.html*** page:

```
<body>
  <div id="parent">
        <div id="child"></div>

  </div>
</body>
```

parent `div` has width 900, height 800

I would like the child `div` located on the top right corner of parent `div`, so, I define CSS for child `div` as following:

```
#child {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 300px;
  height: 30px;
}
```

The CSS is fine that it makes the child `div` located on the top right corner of parent `div`.

**But**, if I change(smaller) the browser window size, the child `div` get disappeared(hided) at some point.

How to make the child `div` always visible but still located 
at the top right corner of parent div no matter how the browser window size is changing?

Answer (score 2):

Give the parent relative position so the child's position is relative to it.

```
#parent {
  position: relative;
  width: 900px;
  height: 800px;
}


#child {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 300px;
  height: 30px;
}
```

EDIT: I misunderstood what you were asking, and now when I read it, I see you want the child div to stay visible on the page no matter what, not just in the upper left corner of the parent. To do this, you need to bind to the window resize event and change the position of the child div when the window width is less than the parent width. Change the right position by the difference.

ok, here's the jquery that will do what I *think* you're asking it to do:

```
$(function(){
  $(window).resize(function(){
    var delta = parseInt($('#parent').width(), 10) - parseInt($(window).width(), 10);
    if (delta > 0) {
      $('#child').css('right', delta);
    }
  }); 
});
```

Two things:

1. if you resize the window quickly, the child div doesn't always return to the far right corner. I'm not sure if this is a timing issue where the width of the window obtained is after it has actually moved farther or what, but this works much better when you resize slowly, which leads me to believe there's a better way to do this.
2. this doesn't handle moving the child div if the window was opened up such that it was too small to see the child div in the first place. This could easily be fixed using the same technique to find the best position for the child div, but just when the page loads rather than when it resizes.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you want the parent to be sized you could do one of several things:

1. Set #parent size with max-width instead of width

   ```
   #parent {
       position: absolute;
       max-width: 300px;
       height: 100%;
   }
   ```
2. Size #parent width with percents

   ```
   #parent {
       position: absolute;
       width: 100%;
       height: 100%;
   }
   ```
3. Or just size the #parent using something like this:

   ```
   #parent {
       position: absolute;
       top: 0px;
       bottom: 0px;
       left: 0px;
       right: 0px;
   }
   ```

Using 2 or 3 does pretty much the same thing in this case, but 2 gives more flexibility if you want some extra space around #parent.